# The Iron Man Mark 33, Silver Centurion, has got vibranium blades in it. How does Tony Stark have access to Vibranium?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3, vibranium

As far as I'm aware, Vibranium was exclusively in Wakanda (except for the Vibranium that Ulysses Klaue stole and later gave to Ultron and the Vibranium from Howard Stark that is in Cap's Shield). So how is it possible that Tony Stark has Vibranium?

Comment: Before becoming Iron Man, Tony Stark already had the super power of being filthy rich. He used this power to buy the vibranium.

Comment: Where does it say the blades are made of vibranium?

Comment: Tony knew Klaue, and knew he sold vibranium. Klaue knew Tony, and thought Ultron was working for him when Ultron asked for vibranium. It's not unlikely that Tony had bought vibranium from Klaue in the past.

Answer (score 6):

According to the novelization of *Iron Man 2*, [the new element that Howard Stark synthesized](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Tony_Stark%27s_New_Element) which Tony used to replace the Palladium in the arc reactor is vibranium, although this is not referenced in the film. I don't have a direct quote, but [this site](https://www.comicbookmovie.com/iron_man/iron-man-2-novelization-breakdown-a16341) summarizes it as:

> Cut back to Stark who is building something with lasers and a centrifuge. Jarvis analyzes the molecule. Unknown element, similar to Vibernum, Uranium and Ourains. Jarvis projects an image of endless interlocking triangles forming a circle. He dubs it Vibranium. Stark creates some and pour it into a mold.

From the MCU wiki notes on [vibranium](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Vibranium), the glowing material seen in *Iron Man 2* does resemble their concept of raw vibranium.

> Black Panther production designer Hannah Beachler says "we've come up with this sort of blue, kind of glowing rock. We went around a lot about like, what is vibranium, because we see it in Cap's shield and it’s very much a metal, so we have different stages of vibranium. We’re going to see it a lot in its raw form, not the alloyed form which is sort of the stainless look." [source](http://collider.com/black-panther-things-to-know#production-design-hannah-beachler)

The process for synthesizing the new element does seem to require a great deal of power, so it might not be efficient to synthesize more than the small amounts necessary for the reactors, and for the claws in the Mark 33.

Comment: Hmmmm. I thought (as of Infinity War) Vibranium could not be synthesised. At least, even the super smart Ultron couldn't do it.

Comment: @Adamant: As I indicated, it's of debatable continuity. It could be that Ultron simply couldn't synthesize enough of it to build the body he wanted. It's kind of like how we have turned small amounts of lead into gold through particle bombardment, but it costs so much that it's not anywhere near worth it.

Comment: Can you offer a quote from the book?

Comment: @Valorum: Can't say that I have access to the book, unfortunately, so the best I can do is quote other sites saying that the quote is there.

Comment: ".. what is vibranium? " Well, you know what vibranium is, right? It's this thing called Ultron, and other things. Like lots of things are done with vibranium, including some bad things. But nobody talks about that.